# Организация хранения данных в Postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Есть таблица пользователей. Каждая строка: id, имя, фамилия. Для каждого пользователя необходимо хранить список его друзей, состоящий из id других пользователей. Не хранить же список айди в строке в ячейке!? И не создавать же новую таблицу с друзьями для каждого пользователя?! Я знаю, что в Postgres есть массивы, но хранить массив id в ячейке мне кажется не совсем изящной идеей. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это красиво и правильно реализовать.

Comment: Для реализации связи ‘многие ко многим’ как правило используют отдельную таблицу - ID пользователя и ID друга

Answer (score 0):

Отдельная таблица ходовой вариант, но и поле тип [массив](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/arrays.html) можно добавить в вашу табличку.

Comment: это станет похоже на ответ если вы предложите структуру бд, продемонстрируете приемущества предлагаемого на каких-то кейсах. сейчас это не ответ - комментарий.